# Missing Data in TCP Transmission Using Sockets In C

Tags: c, http, sockets, missing-data

I am downloading an online .dat file in 200 char chunks and am some of the data is missing. Most, but not all chunks download completely but some only partly download, and there are missing characters when I print the recieved data directly to a local text file.

Thank you.

The Program I am using is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define NOT_EOF  1
#define REACHED_EOF 0
#define BUFFER_SIZE 200

struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
socklen_t addr_size;
char inputData[200];
int newsocket;
struct timeval timeout;
char sendStr[100]; 
char method[] = "GET";

char *buffer= (char *)malloc(2*BUFFER_SIZE*sizeof(char));

FILE *testdata=fopen("testRecv.txt","w");

struct addrinfo hints, *result;
memset (&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if(getaddrinfo("www.blahblah.com","80"
                  , &hints, &result)!=0)
{
     freeaddrinfo(result);
     puts("Unable to resolve hostname.");
     exit(1);
 }

 newsocket = socket( result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, 0);
 if(newsocket == FAILURE)
 {
    puts("Unable to create socket.");
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    close(newsocket);
    exit(1);
  }

 memset(&timeout, 0, sizeof(timeout));
 timeout.tv_sec= 10;
 timeout.tv_usec= 0;
 setsockopt(newsocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));
 setsockopt(newsocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));

if(connect(newsocket, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen) == -1)
  {
    puts("Could not connect.");
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    close(newsocket);
   exit(1);
  }

strcpy(sendStr,method);
strcat(sendStr," /");
strcat(sendStr,subdomain);
strcat(sendStr," HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: ");
strcat(sendStr,hostname);
strcat(sendStr,"\r\n\r\n");

if( send(newsocket,sendStr,strlen(sendStr),0) == FAILURE)
 printf("Unable to send message\n");

 while(not_eof=NOT_EOF)
   {
       bytes_recieved=recv(newsocket,buffer,BUFFER_SIZE,0);

       fprintf(testdata,"%s",buffer);

       if(bytes_recieved == 0 || *(buffer+bytes_recieved) == EOF)
       not_eof=REACHED_EOF;
    }
```

Comment: Show us the actual code around `recv()`. Surely you're not calling it just once?

Comment: Is this all of the code? I see no file writes.

Comment: `while(not_eof=NOT_EOF)` That can't be right. In C, `=` is the assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `recv` just once. Since you're in blocking mode, you must call it in a loop and check whether its return value is positive. If it's negative, there's been an error, if it's zero, the socket has been orderly shutdown.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I do have the recieve in a loop elsewhere in the program, and all values are positive, but data is missing. I'll update the above program.

Comment: @Julia Your update makes no sense. Where is `not_eof` changed? How do you assemble the result from the output of each `recv` call?

Comment: I've updated my question to show the requested information in the code.

Comment: @Julia That `fprintf(testdata,"%s",buffer);` is wrong. First, there could be an error and `buffer` could be garbage, second, you must write exactly the number of bytes you received in that iteration, so something like `fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_received, testdata)`

Answer (score 2):

The `recv` call is not guaranteed to receive all of the data in a single call.  With a 200 byte data size, one would expect the entire data in one call, but it may not always be the case.  If it was not all received in one call, you would need to call recv again.

**Edit** The changes as shown (if it is the real code) still seems like it needs work.  The fprintf call is made regardless of the return value.  Thus, the loop executed twice and the second recv call failed, the buffer would be written twice.  Also, I don't think that `buffer` is guaranteed to be null terminated, so the `fprintf(...%s...)` call may have unpredictable results.  It seems, though, the primary issue is that the possibility of a return value of -1 (error case) is not handled.  In theory, that would result in it loop infinitely.  Actually, it would loop infinitely as currently shown regardless since the `while` loop has a single equals and would assign 1 to the flag each iteration (but I assume that is a typo in the edit).

Comment: I keep calling recv until it reaches the end of file so theoretically if I only recieve half the data in each recv eventually I should recieve all of it but with twice the number of calls.  However, actual characters are missing in a couple of places in the data I am receiving. This would lead me to another question. Is it possible for it to be unnsuccessful in recieving data and to have a limited number of trys resulting in some missing data??? I don't know much about this topic, and all I can find on the internet are information pages saying that TCP is reliable.

Comment: It is almost 100% guaranteed a bug in your code somewhere. TCP is reliable, and most web servers are too. e.g you need to account carefully for the return value of recv. You should show us the actual, full, code that receives data and writes it to a file.

Comment: I've updated my question to show all the information you requested in the code.